# Grab value from multiple tables, use count and group by

Tags: sql-server, count, group-by, multiple-tables, multiple-databases

I'm trying to output some data in MSSQL from 3 different tables (status, status & cases) in 2 different databases (global & private).

```
global.status    // contains labels for global status ID's
     fields (id, text)
private.status   // contains labels for private status ID's
     fields (id, text)
private.cases    // contain case information, such as status
     fields (status, count(status) AS amount)
```

I need to compare the status in the cases table with the status ID in the two status tables and output the following:

```
    statusID |    text     | amount
   ----------|-------------|--------
     9993    |    Open     |   24
     9991    |   Closed    |    3
     9992    |   Pending   |   12
```

The reson for having global and private is that private allows custom private status where global is accessible throughout the system.

My unsuccessful attempt with this was the following sql

```
SELECT  c.status, 
    COUNT(c.status) as amount, 
    ss.text,
    gs.text
FROM [DB11111111].dbo].[cases] AS c, [DB11111111].[dbo].[status] AS ss, [global].[dbo].[status] AS gs
WHERE (c.status = ss.id) OR (c.status = gs.id)
GROUP BY c.status, ss.text, gs.text 
ORDER BY amount DESC
```

Do you have any idea what to do??

Comment: Can the same ID be found in both private and global status tables?

Comment: Yeah, the status field in cases contains a number that is equal to the id in either the global.status or the private.status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might union/union all local and global statuses if they are distinct:

```
SELECT  c.status, 
    COUNT(c.status) as amount, 
    s.text
FROM [DB11111111].dbo.[cases] AS c
LEFT JOIN
(
   select id, [text]
     from [DB11111111].[dbo].[status] 
   union all
   select id, [text]
     from [global].[dbo].[status]
) s
  ON c.Status = s.Id
GROUP BY c.status, s.Text
ORDER BY amount DESC
```

If they overlap, you need to define which one takes precedence and use full outer join on them.

```
SELECT  c.status, 
    COUNT(c.status) as amount, 
    s.text
FROM [DB11111111].dbo.[cases] AS c
LEFT JOIN
(
   -- local before global
   select isnull (l.id, g.id) ID
          isnull (l.[text], g.[text]) [text]
     from [DB11111111].[dbo].[status] l
     full outer join [global].[dbo].[status] g
       on l.id = g.id
) s
  ON c.Status = s.ID
GROUP BY c.status, s.Text
ORDER BY amount DESC
```

Comment: This works perfectly!! only changes is some Uppercases and change "s.text" to "cast(s.text as varchar(100))"

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  id, text
        FROM    private
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  id, text
        FROM    global
        ) q
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*) cnt
        FROM    cases
        WHERE   status = q.id
        GROUP BY
                status
        ) c
```

Comment: Thanks! this works 100% as well, but the other solution only gives output when count is not 0, my bad for not specifying it..